# "Perry and he" vs "He and Perry"

Tags: grammar

Although I understand that both "Perry and he" and "He and Perry" mean the same thing, which is more grammatically correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Perry and he"

While both phrases are grammatically correct, in this particular case the proper name "Perry" is more specific than the general pronoun "he", so by following the convention of listing more specific terms first, "Perry" should be first.